# Schema registry incompatible changes

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

In all the documentation it’s clear described how to handle compatible changes with Schema Registry with compatibility types.
But how to introduce incompatible changes without disturbing the downstream consumers directly, so that the can migrated in their own pace?
We have the following situation (see image) where the producer is producing the same message in both schema versions:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afLMW.jpg)

The problem is how to migrated the app’s and the sink connector in a controlled way, where business continuity is important and the consumer are not allowed to process  the same message (in the new format).

Answer (score 1):

> consumer are not allowed to process the same message (in the new format).

Your consumers need to be aware of the old format while consuming the new one; they need to understand what it means to consume the "same message". That's up to you to code, not something Connect or other consumers can automatically determine, with or without a Registry.

In my experience, the best approach to prevent duplicate record processing across various topics is to persist unique ids (UUID) as part of each record, across all schema versions, and then query some source of truth for what has been processed already, or not. When not processed, insert these ids into that system after the records have been.

This may require placing a stream processing application that filters already processed records out of a topic before the sink connector will consume it

Comment: This could indeed be a solution which properly will work, but it's hard to find best practices when dealing with incompatible changes and try to still have a decoupled architecture. 

Do you mean its a tradeoff, to either consuming the same message in new format or having a streaming application filters the topic (V2) before the  sink connector consumes it (with a small down time for the connector)?

Comment: I can't think of any way around it as Kafka doesn't know you're producing a similar event more than once. Therefore you'll be coupled to the "state store" that tracks what's been processed, and if that's down, then your whole consumer pipeline is broken

Answer (score 0):

I figure what you are looking for is kind of an equivalent to a topic-offset, but spanning multiple ones. Technically this is not provided by Kafka and with good reasons I'd like to add. The solution would be very specific to each use case, but I figure it boils all down to introducing your own functional offset attribute in both streams.

Consumers will have to maintain state in regards to what messages have been processed when switching to another topic filtering out messages that were processed from the other topic. You could use your own sequence numbering or timestamps to keep track of process across topics. Using a sequence will be easier keeping track of the progress as only one value needs to be stored at consumer end. When using UUIDs or other non-sequence ids will potentially require a more complex state keeping mechanism.

Keep in mind that switching to a new topic will probably mean that lots of messages will have to be skipped and depending on the amount this might cause a delay that you need to be willing to accept.